# Accessing params attribute in CarrierWave Image Uploader method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I would like to access the :default_mat attribute found in the params hash within a CarrierWave Uploader method so that I can use a specific colored mat for image processing.

```
class ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

#....

 def frame_image
  manipulate! do |img|
    matID = params[:photo][:default_mat]
    if img.width / img.height < 2
      bg_image = MiniMagick::Image.open("http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/luminoto-modal/#{matID}.jpg")

end
```

In the debugger, I can see the value for :default_mat is 3 as shown below

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", autthenticity_token"=>"yZHusEs7hTwAQWfN2OMGRpzF8qCqJwW74QEeY7EEzR0=", "photo"=>{"default_mat"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Add Photo", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"photos"}
```

but the following line of code returns

```
>> params[:photo][:default_mat]
#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for #<ProductImageUploader::Uploader70281603335700:0x007fd76a573a98>>
```

How do I access that line of code?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 3):

`params` hash is only available within **Controller actions**. It is not available in models, Carrierwave Uploaders or any other place for that matter. This is the reason you get the below error when you try to access it in the `ProductImageUploader` class:

`#<NameError: undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<ProductImageUploader::Uploader70281603335700:0x007fd76a573a98>>`

`params[:photo][:default_mat]` would be available in the `Controller#action` which receives parameters via a HTTP `GET`(as query string) or a `POST`(like posting parameters via a form) request.

In order to access value of `params[:photo][:default_mat]` in `ProductImageUploader`, you could store its value as a *virtual attribute* in the instance of your model which mounts `ProductImageUploader` class as a CarrierWave Uploader. After this, access the stored value in the `frame_image` method using `model.attribute_name` where `attribute_name` is the virtual attribute that you created.

For example:

```
## Model
class ModelName {
  # ...
  attr_accessor :attribute_name
  # ...
}

## In ProductImageUploader
matID = model.attribute_name
```

Comment: This may work as well, but I have not tested it.  Thanks for your respons

Answer (score 0):

I worked with someone on this and he came up with the following solution.

He noticed that once a new instance was created, all attributes in the params hash prior to the image attribute would be given values, but everything after would be nil.

To work around this, we created a new object instance without the image attribute and then updated the image attribute where it could process and resize the file.

```
def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params.except("image"))
#as soon as you call image equals, the processing starts and all values in the hash after are known
@photo.image = photo_params.delete("image")
if @photo.save
  # @photo.delay.update(image: params[:photo][:image])  #process image in background
  flash[:notice] = "Your new photograph is being processed."
  redirect_to @photo
else
  flash[:notice] =  "Please check that all the fields were entered"
  render 'new'
end
```

end

I can then access the value through model.default_mat in the carrier wave uploader file.